# Direct Image, Blow up and a doubt.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, blowup

Let $X = \mathbb{P}^{n}$ and $\pi : \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ be the blow up morphism of $X$ along a subvariety $Y$ with exceptional divisor $E$.

According to the following answer in mathoverflow [Blowing-up and direct image sheaf](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66980), I have the following questions

1) In this case, it is true that $\pi_{*}(\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-mE)) = I_{Y/X}^{m}$ for $m\geq 1$?

2) I can't understand the answer from the point, Taking Proj this means that there is an embedding... (see last answer please)

I am using this result for $X = \mathbb{P}^{n} $ but, honestly, I don't understand the answer, for sure, because I am new to the subject. Could someone help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If your $Y$ is smooth, the above should answer your question. If $Y$ is not smooth, then things can go very wrong. (Your assumption that $X=\Bbb P^n$ says that $X$ is smooth, which removes the other place things can go wrong.)

Comment: @KReiser.  Thanks for your suggestion. I will read the answer.

Comment: @KReiser. If I have any questions, can I ask here in the comments for you? Thank you.

Comment: @red_trumpet. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: If you have specific questions about my answer, you should put them in this or another question - comments aren't really for big discussions on this site.

Comment: @KReiser. Ok. I will turn the doubts into a new question. Thanks for the tip.